# Create appendix in LyX?

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, appendices, tocloft, minitoc

I use report class, I create appendix in LyX :

1. The definition of the appendix has been defined from the LyX menu Document->Start Appendix Here
2. The contents of Appendices are listed in a separate List of Appendices. The List of Appendices page is defined by `tocloft` command, in the LaTeX preamble:

   \newlistof{appendices}{loa}{DAFTAR LAMPIRAN}
3. The format setting of the heading is consistent with LOF and LOT. These four lines must be written in the LaTeX preamble:

   ```
   \renewcommand{\cftloatitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase} 
   \renewcommand{\cftafterloatitle}{%
    \hfill\null\\[2\baselineskip]\bfseries
   No.Lampiran\hfill\phantom{Halaman}Judul
   Lampiran\phantom{No.Lampiran}\hfill Halaman}
   \renewcommand\cftafterloatitleskip{1\baselineskip}
   \renewcommand{\cftappendicespresnum}{}
   ```

In order to print the chapter headings in List of Appendices, right after the appendix definition (from the menu Document->Start Appendix Here), LaTeX commands are inserted : This is simply copied from book.cls then changed toc to loa.

```
\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
 \refstepcounter{chapter}%
\typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
\addcontentsline{loa}{chapter}%
{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
 \else
\addcontentsline{loa}{chapter}{#1}%
\fi
\else
\addcontentsline{loa}{chapter}{#1}%
\fi
\chaptermark{#1}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
\if@twocolumn
\@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
\else
\@makechapterhead{#2}%
\@afterheading
\fi}
\makeatother
```

To prevent section headings of the appendices printed in TOC, `minitoc` command is used. The package minitoc must be called in the preamble `\usepackage{minitoc}`. And The following command is then inserted right after the appendix definition :

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
```

the problems are : I get the loa as printed :

a word "BAB" printed as `\cftchappresnum` 
[image: loa=DAFTAR LAMPIRAN]

Comment: Instead of code snippets, please provide a (complete, compilable) [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).